# native C++/Win32/MFC calendar control with custom font size

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 to create a native/win32/MFC C++ application.  I have a dialog in which I'd like the user to be able to enter a date.  To do this, I used the CDateTimeCtrl which is just a wrapper around the Win32 common controls.

This is nice, since the user can click the arrow and it drops down a month view, letting them interactively pick the date.

The problem I've run into is that you can not control the font size used in the month view.  It ignores WM_SETFONT and, although the control documentation mentions calls which will tell it to use a custom font (see CDateTimeCtrl::SetMonthCalFont()), those are ignored.

I discovered finally, via a MS tech support incident, that it works in v5 of the common controls but in v6 they changed it to ignore this and just use the current visual style info set in Windows.  According to MS there is no way to get a custom font used, the control in v6 will only use the current Windows visual style.  The only way would be to force use of v5 controls, thus dropping all UI in your app back to v5 controls, or mess around with custom activation contexts (sounds messy).

So, I'm looking for an alternate control.  Can anyone recommend a native/C++/MFC control which provides something similar, but which lets me customize the overall font size?  I'm using a larger than normal font in the dialog and all the other controls, and it looks great except for this calendar control.  So far, my initial searching hasn't yielded anything which looks like the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [SetWindowTheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759827%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. With its help you are able to disable the XP theme just for some controls within your application, keeping others.

According to the MSDN:

> When pszSubAppName and pszSubIdList are NULL, the theme manager removes the previously applied associations. You can prevent visual styles from being applied to a specified window by specifying an empty string, (L" "), which does not match any section entries.

Comment: nice!  That looks like it might do exactly what I need.  I'll test and see what happens tomorrow.

Comment: Its interesting that it says "specifying an empty string" but yet provides a non-empty string as an example.  Their example is L" " which contains a single space.  Doesn't seem to be working, but I'm still trying to figure out which combination of NULL and L" " or L"" to use and for which of those two arguments :)

Comment: Here's an example of using SetWindowTheme to remove visual styles and it seems they pass an empty string for both arguments (http://www.logix-controls.com/SwiftForth/XP-Themes/Using%20Windows%20XP%20Visual%20Styles.txt).  Of course here, like the MSDN docs, an "empty string" appears to be a non-empty string with a single space in it so I guess thats whats intended.  Doesn't seem to be working though.

Comment: This is essentially the correct solution.  You have to disable the theme for the month control which gets shown when you click the drop-down arrow in the date/time picker control.  But its more involved than simple calling SetWindowTheme on the CDateTimeCtrl.  I'll post details as a separate response.

Answer (score 1):

The reply from cha above is the correct solution.  In order to get the control to obey the SetMonthCalFont call, you have to disable the visual theme.  There are some tricks involved though.

1) you can't just call SetWindowTheme on the CDateTimeCtrl object since the call only applies to that immediate window not child windows.  The month drop-down is a child window and thus not affected.  So instead you have to handle the DTN_DROPDOWN notification for the control and in there get the child month control and remove the visual theme from it.

2) The size/pos of the month child control is determined before the DTN_DROPDOWN notification is sent.  So even if you do #1 above, it won't be sized properly.  So, you have to update the size.

3) Apparently the intent really is to pass an empty string not a string with 1 space, despite what the MSDN docs seem to indicate.

4) The code below does not account for the case where the calendar drop-down control is close to the edge of the screen.  Its possible that if this happens, the code would need to be modified to account for it and shift its position so its still visible.

The above info was provided by Dave Anderson in Microsoft Support along with the below code which resolved the problem and got the control displaying correctly with the custom font.

So, I'm calling SetMonthCalFont() on the CDateTimeCtrl object in the dialog InitInstance() and then also handling the DTN_DROPDOWN notification using the below code.

Note that Dave provided a warning that, "This approach relies upon implementation details of the Date and Time Picker control that are subject to change in the future and may cause the code below to break".

```
void DSomeDialog::OnDtnDropdownMyDateTimeCtrl(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
HWND hWndDateTime = (HWND)pNMHDR->hwndFrom;
HWND hWndMonthCal = DateTime_GetMonthCal(hWndDateTime);
HWND hWndDropDown = ::GetParent(hWndMonthCal);
DWORD dwWidth;
WINDOWINFO wi;

if (hWndMonthCal && hWndDropDown)
{
    RECT rcIdeal;

    //
    //  Remove the window theme from the month calendar 
    //  control
    SetWindowTheme(hWndMonthCal, L"", L"");

    //
    //  Get the ideal size of the month calendar control
    ZeroMemory(&rcIdeal, sizeof(rcIdeal));
    MonthCal_GetMinReqRect(hWndMonthCal, &rcIdeal);
    dwWidth = MonthCal_GetMaxTodayWidth(hWndMonthCal);
    if (dwWidth > (DWORD)rcIdeal.right)
    {
        rcIdeal.right = dwWidth;
    }

    //
    //  Add some padding
    InflateRect(&rcIdeal, 3, 3);

    //
    //  Determine the new size of the drop down window such
    //  that the client area of the window is large enough 
    //  to display the month calendar control
    ZeroMemory(&wi, sizeof(wi));
    wi.cbSize = sizeof(WINDOWINFO);
    ::GetWindowInfo(hWndDropDown, &wi);
    AdjustWindowRectEx(&rcIdeal, wi.dwStyle, FALSE, wi.dwExStyle);

    //
    //  Update the size of the drop down window
    ::SetWindowPos(hWndDropDown,
        NULL, 
        0, 
        0, 
        rcIdeal.right - rcIdeal.left, 
        rcIdeal.bottom - rcIdeal.top, 
        SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOOWNERZORDER);
}

*pResult = 0;
}
```